# Route 53 - cross account delegation of APEX record

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53

We're implementing an AWS serverless stack with multiple environments. Trying to follow best practices, we created multiple accounts for different purposes.

There's a **DNS** account, which is supposed to contain all hosted zones related to this project. It has a hosted zone for `example.org`.

We got multiple environments and a corresponding account for each. For now I'll focus on **dev** and **prod**.

This is how the host configuration should look like:

**DEVELOPMENT**

- app.dev.example.org (CloudFront distribution in dev account)
- login.dev.example.org (CloudFront distribution for Cognito Hosted UI in dev account)
- api.dev.example.org (API Gateway in dev account)
- cdn.dev.example.org (CloudFront distribution in dev account)

**PRODUCTION**

- example.org  (CloudFront distribution in prod account)
- login.example.org (CloudFront distribution for Cognito Hosted UI in prod account)
- api.example.org (API Gateway in prod account)
- cdn.example.org (CloudFront distribution in prod account)

**dev** is straighforward. Setting up NS records for subdomain `dev.example.org` using NS servers from hosted zone `dev.example.org` in **dev** account and it's done.

**prod** is tricky, as we'd like to use the APEX record of `example.org`. Additionally, `login.example.org`, `api.example.org` and `cdn.example.org` don't have a common subdomain.

Searching for possible solutions, I came up with the following options:

1. Create hosted zone for `example.org` in production account instead. Delegate subdomains to other accounts (i. e. **dev**) from there.
2. (Not sure): Create a reusable delegation set. This way two hosted zones could be created (if I understood correctly), one in **DNS** account and one in **prod** account. They'd be sharing the same nameservers. I couldn't find out if this works cross-account though and didn't test it yet.
3. (Not Sure): Setting up hosted zones in **prod** for each `login.example.org`, `api.example.org` and `cdn.example.org`. This would allow for setting subdomains APEX records from within `prod` account. This is not a solution for the APEX record of `example.org`. Besides, it's 3 additional hosted zones (just for accomplishing a workaround).

I wanted to see if I miss anything fundamental here and/or if anyone out there had a similar situation and an alternative/better solution. That use-case shouldn't be too exotic?

Comment: Option 1.  Seems pretty simple choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose 1 - that's the easiest.

Or 4 - Use a cross-account access to insert records into the zone in "dns" account from "prod" account.

Also note that the ALIAS records can point to resources in other accounts, they don't have to be in the same one.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Also thought about cross account access (from **prod** to **DNS**) but I guess you wouldn't be able to restrict access on a per-record basis. That'd almost be the same as having the hosted zone in **prod**.

However, ALIAS records could be the way to go. I wasn't aware that you could point them to resources in other accounts. Only need to find out if destination records need to exist when creating an ALIAS. If not, this would be perfect for our needs.